# Two Condition in When in Yup in React

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I wanted to put two conditions that if its `isProduct` or `isBox` is true, then `product_id` should be required. I did this code below and it isnt working

```
 product_id: yup.string().when(['isProduct', 'isBox'], {
    is: true,
    then: yup.string().required('Select product'),
  }),
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Currently, you are checking if both fields are true, in order to check either of the fields is true, you need to override is property to function returning boolean value:

```
product_id: yup.string().when(['isProduct', 'isBox'], {
  is: (isProduct, isBox) => isProduct || isBox,
  then: yup.string().required('Select product'),
}),
```

Ref: https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema

Comment: Sure, just posted.

Comment: Hi did you delete your answer there?

Comment: @Joseph yes I did I believe another answer was matching your requirements and I got busy with other stuff.

Comment: he did not yet got the correct answer. you might want to answer it

Comment: Sure posting now, please upvote and accept if it works!